# Convert arma::cx_mat to array of arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

How do I convert a `arma::cx_mat` to an array of arrays?

The motivation for the conversion is to use `libmatio`, which is a C library, to output a .mat file.

So far I have created a function to convert from `arma:cx_mat` to a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> mat_to_vv(arma::cx_mat &M)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vv(M.n_rows);
    for(size_t i=0; i<M.n_rows; ++i)
    {
        vv[i] = arma::conv_to<std::vector<double>>::from(M.row(i));
    };

    return vv;
}
```

Comment: cx_mat is complex matrix so what type of C-array you want to get?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Good question, I want to save the squared norm. This should be a real number, right? if not, then I want to save the real part only. For the purposes of this question, you can assume that I want to save only the real part of the matrix in a array of double arrays.

Comment: Yes. But if you need get squared norm then why need convert to array?

Answer (score 0):

If you need convert real part from cx_mat into C array of arrays can use this function:

```
double** mat_to_carr(arma::cx_mat &M,std::size_t &n,std::size_t &m)
{
const std::size_t nrows = M.n_rows;
const std::size_t ncols = M.n_cols;
double **array = (double**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(double *));

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (double*)malloc(ncols * sizeof(double));
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < ncols; ++j)
            array[i][j] = M(i + j*ncols).real();
    }

n = nrows;
m = ncols;

return array;
}
```

Note, need free the array when it is no longer needed.
Example:

```
int main()
{
cx_mat X(5, 5, fill::randn);
std::size_t n,m;
auto array = mat_to_carr(X,n,m);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i <  n; ++i)
    {
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j)
          std::cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

for(std::size_t i = 0; i <  n; i++)
        free(array[i]);
free(array);
return 0;
}
```